# Multiply the two textbox values and display the result in third textbox in php,jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have the code to dynamically generate the textboxes. I want to multiply the values of quantity and rate textboxes and display the result in total textbox and post it to next page.

The fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hEByw/ that shows how textboxes are dynamically generated.

I have tried the following part of code to multiply the two textbox values but its not working for me. please see the fiddle for complete code.

```
    //To multiply two textbox values
      $('#qty + counter + ').keyup(calculate);
      $('#rates + counter + ').keyup(calculate);
      function calculate(e)
    {
       $('#total + counter + ').val($('#qty + counter +').val() * $('#rates +         counter+').val());
    }
```

Can any one suggest where am I going wrong or the correct way of doing it. I am new to jquery. Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you tried won't work since `qty` & `rates` are dynamically generated, hence you need to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for it. Try that...

Comment: Try using 'parseFloat()'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
$('#rates + counter + ')
```

It should be made to

```
$('#rates' + counter)
```

EDIT :

I analysed it with jsfiddle but the problem is with your logic. How can you get the counter when you are pressing a key. Counter will be used and it will be undefined once the controls are added.

**Edit 2 :**

At last I came up with the answer.
I had to tweak around a bit but that i hope it will satisfy you

Check This [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hEByw/7/)

Sorry for editing your own link

I just added a title attribute and i used it instead of the counter variable.

```
e.target.title For the counter

title = '+ counter + ' in your HTml
```

Refer the link. Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you Rohith for the help.

Comment: If it has helped you atleast you can vote up... U can see that i am struggling for reputation...;) jus kidding

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using jquery 1.4+:

```
$('#qty' + counter).live('keyup', function(){ calculate(counter); });
$('#rates' + counter).live('keyup', function(){ calculate(counter); });

function calculate(counter)
{
    total = Number($('#qty' + counter).val())*Number($('#rates' + counter).val())'
    $('#total' + counter).val(total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never know the value of counter when the event triggers.

```
$('#qty' + counter).on("blur", function() {
    calculate($(this));
});
$('#rates' + counter).on("blur", function() {
    calculate($(this)); 
});

function calculate(el) {
var counter = el.attr("id").indexOf("qty") != -1 ? el.attr("id").substring(3) : el.attr("id").substring(5);
var qty = isNaN(parseInt($('#qty' + counter).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($('#qty' + counter).val());
var rate = isNaN(parseInt($('#rates' + counter).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($('#rates' + counter).val());
$("#total" + counter).val(qty * rate);
```

}